# Styling in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Im trying to learn how to style with Material UI, but sometimes get stuck with all that parenthesis and curly brackets. It tends to be kind of overwhelming just to change a simple thing. Can someone try explain me what this line of code actually means and what the author are trying to target here.

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles(({ palette }) => ({
  color: ({ color }: { color: string }) => ({
    "&:before": {
      backgroundColor: Color(color).darken(0.3).desaturate(0.2).toString()
    }
  }),
  content: ({ color }: { color: string }) => ({
    position: "relative",
    zIndex: 1,
  }));
```

Comment: to provide an accurate answer we need to know what component these styles are applied to

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what component the author is trying to style, every component has a section in their API that describes how each rule is applied and what dom element is targeted.

If you get confused with short arrow functions you can always rewrite them in a more verbose way like adding some `{}` and return statements, and move the types outside

```js
    

interface ComponentProps {
  color: string;
}

...

  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
    return {
      color: ({ color }: ComponentProps) => {
        return {
          "&:before": {
            backgroundColor: Color(props.color)
              .darken(0.3)
              .desaturate(0.2)
              .toString(),
          },
        };
      },
      content: ({ color }: ComponentProps) => {
        return {
          position: "relative",
          zIndex: 1,
        };
      },
    };
  });
```